# EXTJS chart column with label

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to Show data labels on Extjs 3.4 Chart Column ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply data labels to your bar chart columns by configuring the 'label' property of the series as described in the API docs:

```
   label: {
      display: 'insideEnd',
        field: 'data1',
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        color: '#333',
        'text-anchor': 'middle'
    }
```

Have a read over this: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Bar